Compilation error of quantum espresso
During installation of quantum espresso 7.3.1, I am getting error mentioned in the code block below:
[to be added later]
I am using cmake version 3.22 and latest git version. How to resolve this issue?

Welcome to the site! The more detail you can provide the better. For instance: (1) Do you pass any other options to cmake? (2) What Fortran/C compilers are you using (and do you specify these to cmake)?
Its preferable to have the output in your question written as a code block rather than a screenshot. This makes it easier for users to copy-paste search terms.

Please paste the output from the terminal, into a code block. I have removed your screenshot.

I faced some problem using cmake with the version from GitHub but I don't remember exactly what was the error. Later, I tried simple ./configure and make all command which worked without any error. Maybe you can try this. But make sure to have all the prerequisites installed. You can find step-by-step installation instruction here for g++ gfortran. If you are using oneapi, the ./configure script should be able to detect them automatically. I tested it with QE 7.3.1 in Ubuntu 22.04.4 with both oneapi and gfortran.
